# Liquid Sandpaper Sprayer

Tags: painting, preparation

Let's play "good idea; bad idea"

I have a lot of glossy trim to degloss before painting. I have two bottles of "liquid Sandpaper" and a spray nozzle from a different product (which I have flushed with water).

As a faster way to apply the deglooser, can I use the sprayer before wiping the surface?

Comment: Have you started to use the liquid sander product?  I seem to remember it being more like a thin gel - doesn't seem like that would spray.  Is yours a light liquid like water?

Comment: I'm no fan of chemical deglossers, they depend on your previous layer having a particular paint chemistry.  I'm also no fan of masking, thus no fan of spraying.  Rollers work fine; slow and steady wins the race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Liquid Sand Paper" is a diluted form of the solvent used in gloss paints in the first place, Diethylene glycol monobutyl ether (DEG monobutyl ether). It also contains fine grains of silica (quartz) in suspension. It works by slightly dissolving the surface of the gloss paint and allowing the silica grains to embed themselves in it, which then allows the next layer of paint to adhere.

If you try to volatilize (spray) it, you would not only need high pressure to avoid having the silica clog things up, but it then becomes HIGHLY dangerous to inhale.

Don't try it, that's not what it was designed for.

Comment: Seriously. Don't aerosolize things whose instructions do not authorize that use.